# What is the difference between ">>>" and ">>" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I have just found a piece of JS code that uses `>>>` instead of `>>`.

I have searched Stack Overflow and also Google, but I've found documentation only for `>>` operator.

After a few tests they look the same. Both operators are doing a binary right shift. Trying to use `<<<` fails with a syntax error.

Is this an exception in the JS's interpreter that allows us to use `>>>` also ?

PS: I've tried using `>>>>` but it fails with a syntax error, so something must be different.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @deceze ... (facepalm).. you could've at least leave a few words also. That -1 seems like a hard slap. Anyway, thank you for opening my eyes.

Comment: @helly0d Don't focus on downvotes, it's not a big deal. Anyway, you have no clue if it came from deceze or not. Could have been me :p

Comment: @X.L.Ant Only the first and third sentences are for `deceze` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operator **>>>** is unsigned right shift which shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Zero bits are shifted in from the left. The sign bit becomes 0, so the result is always non-negative.
As You've tried **<<<** (assuming you mean left unsigned shift) which is logically incorrect as there's no signed bit at the end. 
For more information please use this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift)